# Problem with parentheses and mathastext

Tags: brackets, fourier, mathastext

I'll motivate my problem quickly: I make flashcards on my computer using latex, and am in need of certain formatting for this. I've wanted a. computer-readable unified look, which uses non-slanted symbols (so no italic) and preferably has a bold version of all special symbols (greek symbols, the reals and rationals, etc..). I use pdflatex for compiling.

One thing which seemed to accomplish this was `\usepackage[upright]{fourier}` and `\usepackage{mathastext}`. This gives me upright greek symbols, no italic in my math-environment, and a font bolder than cm (thus nicer to read on a screen). However this doesn't work with `\left` and `\right` when using parentheses. One such example is given:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
$\left(\int \frac{1}{x^2+12}dx\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Forgive me if I'm being ignorant. I'm new to this forum, so any help is appreciated:)
Any comments on alternatives to the upright fourier font or ways to write upright in math-environments, that seem applicable for my use case, is very welcome.

Comment: Try adding the option `nosmalldelims` to mathastext

Comment: This works! Thank you a lot:)

Comment: Alongside the `nosmalldelims` pointed out by @mbert there is also `noparenthesis` which is stronger as it will tell `mathastext` to not touch `(` and `)` even when not used with `\left/\right`.

Comment: These work quite well. Is there something equivalent for not loading the mathbb fonts? These don't let mathalfa point to the fonts I actually want. I'm having a hard time figuring out the documentation. kind regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

you can restore the delcode of ()

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\edef\tmp{\delcode`(\the\delcode`(\relax\delcode`)\the\delcode`)\relax}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\tmp

\begin{document}
$\left(\int \frac{1}{x^2+12}dx\right)$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `upright` option of the `fourier` package means "French style" maths, roman letters remain in italics. That is why you need `mathastext` here. Especially if you care for bold math, you could try lualatex instead of pdflatex. Compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{fourier-otf}
\begin{document}
$\left(\int \frac{1}{x^2+12}dx\right)$
\end{document}
```

with lualatex outputs:[image]